# Jenkinsfile/Groovy: why is result of dictionary AND integer an integer?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, boolean-expression, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

In Groovy/Jenkinsfile declarative syntax, **why is the result of the boolean `AND` operation on dictionary, dictionary, and integer objects an integer instead of boolean true/false?**

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage( "1" ) {
      steps {
        script {
          a = [:]
          a.a = [:]
          a.a["a"] = "1"
          a.a["b"] = "2"
          echo "${a}"
          echo "${a.a}"
          echo "${a.a.size()}"
          def my_bool = (a && a.a && a.a.size())
          echo "my_bool ${my_bool}"
        }
      }
    }
    stage( "2" ) {
      when {
        expression { true == (a && a.a && a.a.size()) } // Fails because result is integer "2", not boolean "true"
      }
      steps {
        script {
          echo "hello, world!"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My biases from other programming languages led me to think that `a && a.a && a.a.size()` should implicitly be converted to a boolean value. The `echo` reveals that the value is integer `2`.

**What is the Jenkins/Groovy idiomatic way to deal with this?** I.e. if a stage is conditional on "dictionaries being non-null and having nonzero size", what is the idiomatically correct/preferred way to write that conditional?

---

**Update:**
Note: the `echo "my_bool ${my_bool}"` statement prints "`my_bool 2`". This is with Jenkins version 2.222.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expression { a?.a?.size() }
```

or even

```
expression { a?.a }
```

Comment: Or even just `a.a` as I don't believe `a` can be null 

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate why this works and the OP's attempt gives 2?

Comment: Do you want to say that `echo "my_bool ${my_bool}"` prints `2`  at stage 1?  In usual groovy script (not in jenkins) the same code is printing `my_bool true` ... What's the version of Jenkins pipeline do you have?

Comment: @daggett - updated my post to note that `echo "my_bool ${my_bool}"` prints `my_bool 2`. If I go to `Jenkins > About Jenkins`, I see version `2.222.3`.

Comment: @daggett - Ian W's question was on my mind as well. Again - my experience with other programming languages is probably biasing me, but I would have expected the result of `(object1 && object2 && object3)` to be a _boolean_ rather than `object3`. Something slightly odd about the observed behavior, to someone with a primarily `C`-family background.

Comment: your expectation absolutely correct. in version groovy 2.4+ i see the boolean result. https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5099635114770432 It's possible you have old version of jenkins pipeline plugin (with old version of groovy) that evaluates expression differently...